# Push new data from mysql to elastic search

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I want to make a script in python which keeps track of new data and inserts into elastic search.

What could be the ideal way to do that.

One approach I can think of to create two columns in mysql table namely process_start and process_done that will deal with 0 and 1. New rows can be detected when both flags are 0 first time. then process_start could be 1 when row is read and process_done can be 1 when data is inserted into elastic search.

But problem with this approach is if I run script more than one time, then they could read the same row of table as I have experienced that.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse mysql binlog and write data to es.

Sample code:

```
pip install mysql-replication
```

```
[root@mha-1 script]# cat mysql-replication.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pymysqlreplication import BinLogStreamReader
from pymysqlreplication.row_event import (
    DeleteRowsEvent,
    UpdateRowsEvent,
    WriteRowsEvent,
)
import sys
import json

def main():
    mysql_settings = {'host': '192.168.3.130',
                      'port': 3306, 'user': 'replicator', 'passwd': 'yourpass'}
    stream = BinLogStreamReader(
        connection_settings=mysql_settings,
        server_id=101,
        blocking=True,
        only_schemas=['zow'],
        only_events=[DeleteRowsEvent, WriteRowsEvent, UpdateRowsEvent],
        resume_stream=True,
        log_file='mysql-bin.000013', log_pos=6197)

    for binlogevent in stream:
        for row in binlogevent.rows:
            event = {"schema": binlogevent.schema, "table": binlogevent.table, "log_pos": binlogevent.packet.log_pos}
            if isinstance(binlogevent, DeleteRowsEvent):
                event["action"] = "delete"
                event["values"] = dict(row["values"].items())
                event = dict(event.items())
            elif isinstance(binlogevent, UpdateRowsEvent):
                event["action"] = "update"
                event["before_values"] = dict(row["before_values"].items())
                event["after_values"] = dict(row["after_values"].items())
                event = dict(event.items())
            elif isinstance(binlogevent, WriteRowsEvent):
                event["action"] = "insert"
                event["values"] = dict(row["values"].items())
                event = dict(event.items())
            print json.dumps(event)
            sys.stdout.flush()

    stream.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Okay, let's run the sample code for testing

```
[root@mha-1 script]# python mysql-replication.py
{"action": "insert", "table": "t2", "log_pos": 4622, "values": {"tname": "hh", "id": 7}, "schema": "zow"}
{"log_pos": 4904, "after_values": {"tname": "ii", "id": 7}, "action": "update", "table": "t2", "before_values": {"tname": "hh", "id": 7}, "schema": "zow"}
{"log_pos": 4904, "after_values": {"tname": "ii", "id": 7}, "action": "update", "table": "t2", "before_values": {"tname": "hh", "id": 7}, "schema": "zow"}
{"action": "delete", "table": "t2", "log_pos": 5169, "values": {"tname": "ii", "id": 7}, "schema": "zow"}
```

The output result is already available, and subsequent writing to es will be ok